# БоГдан / БоҐдан = одне і теж ім’я чи різні?

Tags: власні-назви

Доволі часто таке трапляється у документах, які видавалися при примусовому переселенні людей в 1944-1946 рр, а також можна стикнутися з цим і сьогодні.

Отож, наприклад, є випадок, що в офіційних документах (паспорт, свідоцтво про народження та диплом бакалавра) допущена помилка у написанні **БоГдан / БоҐдан.**

Питання: чи це ніякої ролі не грає в ідентифікації людини, тобто помилка незначна, тому вважатиметься, що це варіантність імені (одне і те ж ім’я), чи все ж імена будуть різні?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ім'я одне і теж, просто Боґдан це транслітерація від польського "[Bogdan](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farben_Lehre)" (зверніть увагу на ім'я піаніста). Така ж справа з іменем віце-маршала Сенату [Боґдана Борусевича](http://www.polradio.pl/5/38/Artykul/233340). Як зазначено у книзі "[Слов'янські особовi iмена украïнцiв](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=M-sHKtbjF2EC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22%D0%B1%D0%BE%D2%91%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%22&source=bl&ots=1IgoChRxKe&sig=-4g154NaLaiOlbDS4I4gTE_YBjE&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje9c_b1LTbAhXLMewKHRhcCaUQ6AEITDAK#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%BE%D2%91%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%22&f=false)": "У наші дні ім'я та ойконім Боґдан пишуть та вимовляють у відповідності до норм суч. укр. літ. мови" (тому в українській мові пишемо Богдан з наголосом на букву "а"). В Україну це слово принесли волхви і на території нашої країни найчастіше воно зустрічається у гуцулів.